# How to configure Postfix to accept connections from several hosts outside LAN?

Tags: postfix-mta, ssl, sasl

I have Postfix 2.3 on Centos 5.5 server.
I followed this how to http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postfix_sasl to configure Postfix to accept only TLS connections and reject plain authentication.
It seems that it working but only from the local machine (Postfix server itself) If I try to 'telnet' mail server from outside of the LAN connection immediately closes after it established.

```
telnet mail.some-server.com 25
Trying aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd...
Connected to mail.some-server.com (aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd).
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I have spent full day on reading Postfix manual and tried set permissive mode but not got even closer to the solution.
Please help.

Comment: Belongs to http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem was in Postfix configuration of **inet_interfaces** that was restricting Postfix to listen on *localhost* only.

Solution: edit **inet_interfaces** in the file **/etc/postfix/main.cf**

```
# Listen to all interfaces rather than strict to localhost
inet_interfaces = all
```

Reload Postfix configuration:

```
postfix reload
```

Comment: This solved it for me too :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use 'postfix check'
2. Use 'tailf /var/log/mail.warn', or replace 'tailf' with 'tail -n 100' just to see the last 100 rows of the log.

The point is, something in the settings is wrong, and therefor the server can't handle the request properly. remember to reload postfix.

Comment: Oh thanks! I forgot about my post since I figured the problem. My Postfix was configured to listen on localhost only.